# Background Image using Skew is causing a gap?

Tags: html, css

Okay so when using a background image on a skewed element, it seems to be causing a gap and I'm not sure why. When the item is not skewed, there is no gap. What is the reason for this and how can I fix the issue?

You can see the issue on [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/silvawebdesigns2020/pen/KKpRdmX).

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="navbar-nav">
  <li id="menu-item-143" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-143 nav-item"><a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-144" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-144 nav-item"><a href="#gameplay" class="nav-link">Gameplay</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-145" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-145 nav-item"><a href="#crowd" class="nav-link">Crowd Funding</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-146" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-146 nav-item"><a href="#mail" class="nav-link">Mail</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-147" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-147 nav-item"><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-download menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-148 nav-item"><a target="_blank" href="#!" class="nav-link">Download</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: #000;
}

a {
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 0;
    background: url(https://indie.nathandasilva.co.uk/wp-content/themes/indie/assets/img/menu-bg.png);
    background-size: 1px 63px;
    height: 63px;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: skew(0);
}

.navbar-nav {
    padding: 16px 0px 16px 21px !important;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.navbar-nav > li a {
    transform: skew(0deg);
    font-family: 'BebasNeue-Regular', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 26px !important;
}
```

Skewed Version:

[image: Skewed]

Normal Version:

[image]

Comment: why not skewing the whole container instead? to make sure you have only one skewed element and no gap

Comment: Issue is with your background being way too small, you're relying on `background-repeat` which clearly having problems with skewed elements, Add `background-repeat:no-repeat;` so see what happens and try with a bigger image.

Comment: Saved out a new asset of background-size: 170px 73px, still had the same issue. Added the skew to the UL element and that resolved the issue, thanks!